# Implementing .all() for a list of booleans?

Tags: python, list, boolean

Numpy has a great method `.all()` for arrays of booleans, that tests if all the values are true. I'd like to do the same without adding numpy to my project. Is there something similar in the standard libary? Otherwise, how would you implement it?

I can of course think of the obvious way to do it:

```
def all_true(list_of_booleans):
    for v in list_of_booleans:
        if not v:
            return False
    return True
```

Is there a more elegant way, perhaps a one-liner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is; it is called [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), surprisingly. It is implemented *exactly* as you describe, albeit in C. Quoting the docs:

> Return `True` if all elements of the *iterable* are true (or if the
>   iterable is empty). Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def all(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if not element:
>             return False
>     return True
> ```
>
> *New in version 2.5.*

This is not limited to just booleans. Note that this takes an *iterable*; passing in a generator expression means only enough of the generator expression is going to be evaluated to test the hypothesis:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> c = count()
>>> all(i < 10 for i in c)
False
>>> next(c)
11
```

There is an equivalent [`any()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with 2.4 :-) I'll roll out my own.

Comment: That *is* unfortunate; 2.4 is quite.. ancient, by now.

Comment: I'm aware of this fact :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar function, called [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all).